# How to click a button without any id or name attributes

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to have selenium click a button on a webpage. Cannot find the element to make it click.

```
<button type="submit" class="xButton xCTA xSubmit">
  <span>Enter</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Random google for "selenium, find by class": https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-class-name-locator/

Comment: Can you add the rest of the html to your question?  It will help us to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='xButton xCTA xSubmit'].click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Enter')]").click()
```

Any of those should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Chris. I keep getting an "element not visible" error, event after putting a 20 second timeout on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Though the `<button>` have no `or` attribute you can still use the other attributes, e.g. **`class`**, **`innerText`**, etc.

To `click()` on the element with text as **Enter** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable()* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Python* and `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.xButton.xCTA.xSubmit[type='submit'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *Java* and `XPATH`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='xButton xCTA xSubmit']/span[text()='Enter']"))).click();
  ```